# Are temporaries with Eigen::Ref discarded on copy and are move semantics supported?

Tags: c++, eigen

The `Eigen::Ref<T>` class can create temporaries if `T` is const qualified. The class is implemented as a derived class of `MapBase` and the const version has a member of the referenced type. So from what I understand, the temporaries are stored in the `Ref` object and the `MapBase` points into that member's data when a temporary is held.

Now the question is, what is the lifetime of that temporary? From the code [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Ref_8h_source.html) and some experiments, it seems it's simply the lifetime of the `Ref`. Surprisingly though, the temporary seems to be discarded on copy and there doesn't seems to be any way to use move semantics effectively.

To me, this is would be surprising behavior and it was a pain to even find the source of the issue because the interface doesn't give you any clues that temporaries even exist. Also, they are documented, but nothing is said about their behavior.

Also, if I really can't copy or move them without invalidating the temporary and can't control whether a temporary is created, then there is no way to use them as a member or safely put them in a `std::vector` for example, right?

Update:
The following code causes an invalid read (reported by valgrind). The non-reduced version caused my program to crash.

```
struct S {
    Ref<const VectorXf> ref;
    explicit S( Ref<const VectorXf> const& r )
        : ref( r ) {}
};

int main() {
    const MatrixXf mat = MatrixXf::Constant( 4, 4, 1.25f );
    S s{ mat.row( 0 ) };
    return s.ref(0); // invalid read
}
```

It appears that merely copying is not the problem, but creating a temporary and copying it is, as the following works fine:

```
int main() {
    const MatrixXf mat = MatrixXf::Constant( 4, 4, 1.25f );
    Ref<const VectorXf> ref{mat.row(0)};
    S s{ ref };
    return s.ref(0); // fine
}
```

Update2:
I think the following code show what's happening

```
Ref<const VectorXf> make(MatrixXf const & mat) {
    Ref<const VectorXf> ref (mat.row(0));
    Ref<const VectorXf> ref2(ref);
    return ref2;
}

int main() {
    const MatrixXf mat = MatrixXf::Constant( 4, 4, 1.25f );
    return make(mat)(0); // invalid read
}
```

The problem is that creating one `Ref` from another means that the newly created one references the temporary in the original one, so its validity now depends on the lifetime of the first `Ref`. Since the `Ref` class is not copy assignable, this doesn't happen easily with local variables.

The possibility of creating one `Ref` from another was misleading me into expecting semantics that aren't actually there.

Comment: `Eigen::Ref<T>` only creates temporaries for `const T`. The temporary should not get discarded on copy. Can you post a [mre] where that happens? Also, you can't use `Ref` in a `std::vector` since it is not copy-assignable (in fact `operator=` is overloaded in the non-const case to overwrite the referred-to matrix.

Comment: Right they are copy constructible but not copy assignable. The copy construction is kinda tricky and is also what caused my problem. And you can put the refs into a vector, as in, it compiles https://godbolt.org/z/Pfv1379Ej . But it's a really bad idea because I think it basically never works correctly.

Comment: Having the copy work as it does right now seems pretty bad. I think they should either be completely immobile or, preferably, move only. I would also want a type that's actually just a reference and can't carry temporaries around, but can still point to const.

Comment: `Ref<const X> const&` kind-of behaves like a `X const&` with any other class `X`. This would lead to the same problem as your example: `struct S { const int& ref; explicit S(const int& r) : ref(r) {} };` (if you initialize it with a temporary integer). Any suggestions for improving the documentation are of course welcome!

Comment: Creating a `std::vector<Ref<...>>` is indeed very dangerous (and probably hard to prevent -- and with very much care might have a valid use case) ...

Comment: It all works fine as long as no temporaries are created because then the refs behave basically like pointers. So the non const case is always fine. I guess it makes sense that a class called ref mimics the semantics of language references, but just as with language references, the moment you want to do more than just take function arguments or reference a local variable, you're better off with a pointer. Unfortunately there's no Ptr class available that mimics pointer behavior, i.e. no temporaries and trivial copy construction and assignment. I'll try to adapt the Ref code to do that.

Comment: Regarding `Ptr`: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/912 (I don't think any actual work has been done on this yet)